# Is there a way to consume enabled extensions in my webview automatically

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I want to be able to display icons and use the colors of the theme enabled as well as LSP data. and display it. I know I can just build an extension pack but this is not quite What I was looking for. I want to embed editor groups in my webview as well. But also use the data they collect and display it in a custom manner

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: all useful theme colors are part of the injected style in the Webview, read the doc or use the Developer Tools